# JQuery Mobile "Error Loading Page" message

Tags: jquery

Is is possible, for debugging purposes, to change the default jquery mobile "Error Loading Page" message to one that contains more detailed information of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, but you may not want to do that for security reasons.  In the mean time, just use Firefox with the debugging console inside Firebug.  It will catch and display Javascript errors.  You can then troubleshoot and debug the Javascript and JQuery errors from there.

Comment: Ahhh, good oll firefox, I was just about to ask the same question! +1 here!

Comment: You should have the answer too, I've been trying everything for months and just dealing with it!