# jQuery Mobile - handling JS errors on new page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I encountered a never ending "Loading" dialog when moving from one page to the next, because the next page had a JS error in it.

Is there a way to avoid the loading message and instead show an error message?

Edit: 
To clarify, I am looking for a solution that displays an error message to the user (like "We encountered a problem. Please contact the system administrator"). It would also be great to return to the previous page, so a user can continue to use the app. As it is right now, a JS error stops them cold in their tracks.

Comment: You could just look at your browser's console output to see what the problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Mobile "Error Loading Page" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472536/jquery-mobile-error-loading-page-message)

Comment: I should clarify, I am looking for a solution that displays an error message to the user (like "We encountered a problem. Please contact the system administrator").  It would also be great to return to the previous page, so they can continue to use the app.  I can certainly use firebug/debugger to find the issue, but I am thinking more about the end user's experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to detect and react to page loads that failed using something like:

```
     $('#pagename').live('pageloadfailed', function () {
     alert('page load failed.');
     });
```

But a true Javascript error is handled at the browser level, and will stop execution when encountered.

Your best best would be to encapsulate the potential javscript problem in a `try ... catch` block and add some logic around it.